# Open source tool to automate testing of publish subscribe connection

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, tools

I recently learned how to use SOAP UI to test REST and SOAP Webservices. But now, I am looking for a similar open-source software to test Publish-Subscribe connections for performing automated testing. I want to use several test cases. Please suggest me tools that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to look for tools which support [Messaging Queue Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queuing_service), if you're limited to free and open source, I can recommend to choose one of the following, both support [JMS API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service):

1. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) -  [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)
2. [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) - [JMS](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.1/jms.html#jms)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I also use Hermes JMS with SOAP UI for testing messaging queue services? I will be using TIBCO  EMS as a communication bus.

Comment: Actually looking into [Working with JMS Messages](https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages.html) guide you should be able to test it using SoapUI as well

Answer (score 1):

In our team, we used SpecFlow to test the service based test cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a tool to post HTTP messages for a functional tests, have a look at RestAssured, Karate, Postman.